# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Spawn.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Spawn.cs:38). как решить ошибку?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вылезла ошибка `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Spawn.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Spawn.cs:38)` именно в самом юнити, а не в Visual Studio. Как решить?

Вот код:

```
public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject [] Spawner;

    public Transform[] spawnTree;
    private int randX;
    private int randY;

    private int rand;
    private int randPosition;
    private float spawnRate = 120f;
    float nextSpawn;
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)           
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            rand = Random.Range(0, Spawner.Length);
            randPosition = Random.Range(0, spawnTree.Length);

            Instantiate(Spawner[rand], spawnTree[randPosition].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка в строке 38, а 38 строка - это где?

Comment: А в массивах точно есть элементы? Или их количество НОЛЬ?

Comment: ТС, по приведенному фрагменту кода возможна только одна причина указанной ошибки - какой-то из массивов (или оба) не содержит элементов, но проинициализированы (иначе было бы NullRef-исключение). В этом случае генерация случайного индекса будет равна 0 (от 0 до 0), но в массиве нет элемента под этим индексом, т.е. Length == 0. Возможно, Вы в Инспекторе заполнили массивы, но где-то в коде очищаете их или пересоздаете, н-р Spawner = new GameObject [0]; Либо не заполнили даже в испекторе. Добавьте логироание, что бы перед Instantiate() выводить число элементов в Ваших массивах.

Answer (score -1):

Вместо `Spawner.Length` поставь `Spawner.Length-1`. Потому что С# любит считать с 1

Comment: Это лишнее. Перегрузка Random.Range(int, int) уже предусматривает использование второго целочисленного аргумента "не включительно".